# Difference between the in keyword and __contains__ in Python

Tags: python

I was wondering if some one could explain the difference between the "in" keyword of Python and the **contains** method

I was working with a sample list and found this behavior. When are the two supposed to be used? Is there some efficiency that can be achieved if I use one over the other.

```
    >>> my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
    >>> my_list.__contains__("a")
    True
    >>> "a" in my_list
    True
```

Comment: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

Answer (score 8):

The `__contains__()` method of an an object is called when you use the `in` statement.

For lists this is pre-defined, but you can also define your own class, add a `__contains__` method and use `in` on the instances of that class.

You should be using `in` and not call `__contains__()` directly.

Answer (score 5):

From the [**docs**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> For the list and tuple types, x in y is true if and only if there
>   exists an index i such that x == y[i] is true.
>
> string types, x in y is true if and only if x is a substring of y. An
>   equivalent test is y.find(x) != -1.
>
> For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, x in
>   y is true if and only if `y.__contains__(x)` is true.
>
> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do
>   define `__iter__()`, x in y is true if some value z with x == z is
>   produced while iterating over y. If an exception is raised during the
>   iteration, it is as if in raised that exception.
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines
>   `__getitem__()`, x in y is true if and only if there is a non-negative integer index i such that x == y[i], and all lower integer indices do
>   not raise `IndexError` exception.

Answer (score 2):

Like most magic methods, the `__contains__` method is not meant to be called directly.  The reason `__contains__` exists is precisely so that you can write `obj in container` instead of having to use method-call syntax.  So you should use `obj in container`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `"a" in my_list` actually calls `__contains__` method of `my_list` if defined.

If `__contains__` is not defined then `__iter__` is used, if that's not defined then `__getitem__` is used.

`__contains__` is great way for some containers or iterables to implement fast membership check without looping through the whole sequence, for example `range()`:

```py
>>> %timeit 10**5 in range(10**9)
159 ns ± 1.16 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

---

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

> For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, `x in y` returns `True` if `y.__contains__(x)` returns a true value, and `False` otherwise.

> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `True` if some value `z`, for which the expression `x is z or x == z` is true, is produced while iterating over `y`. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if `in` raised that exception.

> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `True` if and only if there is a non-negative integer index `i` such that `x is y[i] or x == y[i]`, and no lower integer index raises the `IndexError` exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if in raised that exception).

Comment: How about __iter__() ? When will this be called?

Comment: @MohammadKholghi It depends on the type. If a class doesn't define `__contains__` then `__iter__` is used for membership check. Lists use `__iter__` when you loop over them to return a special `list_iterator` object.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations